# Android (Fragments)

Tags: android-fragments

I installed bottom bar and sync I faced this problem:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 11 declared in library [com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.1.1] C:\Users\Gowtham\AndroidStudioProjects\Bottom_bar\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.roughike\bottom-bar\2.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.roughike.bottombar" to force usage
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is unclear? Your minimum SDK must be 11 due to dependency on whatever bottom-bar is.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly specify your one of library required minimum SdkVersion is 11 and you're using minSdkVersion 8. Change your minSdkVersion to 11 in your `build.gradle` file.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ng.app"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

This override value of `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Error:Timeout waiting to lock cp_proj class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Gowtham\AndroidStudioProjects\Bottom\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Gowtham\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_2byzaor5edpoicoq4bdr5gl88\cp_proj). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 4264
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: Initialize cache
Lock file: C:\Users\Gowtham\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_2byzaor5edpoicoq4bdr5gl88\cp_proj\cache.properties.lock

Comment: delete everything under C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches. There is a cache.properties.lock that is holding a global lock which is preventing you from running your script.

Comment: Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.10'.

Comment: I want to create a bottom bar like in online shopping (Home, Cart. Fav,...etc).

Comment: I don't have much idea of android app development.